# modifying the last or first node of a linked list?

Tags: java

Say I have a linked list called L that stores linked lists so:

```
LinkedList <LinkedList<String>> L
```

if I do `L1 = L.getLast()` can I also say `L.getLast.add("something")` or `L1.add("something")` and will that add "something" to the last list or only the local instance of that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "local instance of that list"? We're dealing with reference types here - what's stored in the outer list is simply *references* to instances of lists. When you fetch the last element, that just gets you a copy of a *reference*. It doesn't matter how you access the object, you're still modifying that single object.

You've made your example more complicated than it needs to be by creating a `LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>`, but fundamentally this is the same issue as we can easily demonstrate with a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder y = x; // Copies the *reference*, not an object
y.append("foo");
System.out.println(x); // Prints "foo"
```

Again, we've got a single `StringBuilder` object, and the values of both `x` and `y` are references to that same object. It doesn't matter how you modify it, the modification will be visible however you then access the object.

Or if you want to use lists as an example:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> list2 = list1;
list1.add("help");
System.out.println(list2.size()); // Prints 1
```

This is crucial to understanding Java - *all* classes work the same way. The value of an expression is *never* an object; it's always either a reference or a primitive value.

Answer (score 1):

> will that add "something" to the last list or only the local instance of that list?

Since you are adding to same list pointed by two reference (not instance), bothe lines of code will work same.

Given

```
LinkedList <LinkedList<String>> L
```

Following two fragments will work exactly same

- Having a local reference (it's not called instance what you wrote) pointing to last node.

  ```
  L1 = L.getLast() 

  L1.add("something")
  ```
- Not having a local reference but using the reference stored in outer `LinkedList L`

  ```
  L.getLast.add("something")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

L1 and l.getLast() both refer to same Object (Last in parent linked list).

You can use L1.addLast("something") or l.getlast().addlast("something") will add "something" to last in last list.